# Using static I can load one css file but am having an issue loading another in the same directory

Tags: django, django-templates

Quick Summary: I can get 'base.css' to load but not 'index.css', they are in the same directory.

I have a 'base.html' file and a 'base.css' file, all other .html files extend 'base.html.' Using `static` to load the 'base.css' is working without a problem. It is when I try to have my 'index.html' extend 'base.html' and then also load the 'index.css' file that I am running into an issue. If I go to the js console and click 'sources' it will say 'Could not find the original style sheet.' in reference to 'index.css'. I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is the directory for the app 'core':

```
core/ 
  templates/
    core/
      base.html
      index.html
  static/
    core/
      base.css
      index.css
```

Base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Generic</title>
    <meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/base.css' %}"> <!-- loading without issue -->

   {% block head %}

   {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
  {% block body %}

  {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/index.css' %}"> <!-- not loading -->
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <!-- content -->
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried that and it returns `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: <ExtendsNode: extends "core/base.html"> must be the first tag in the template.`

Comment: Is this on the dev server? Have you run collect_static?

Comment: @IainShelvington it is on the dev server and I have not done that because I am not sure what it is. I'll look into it thanks.